# Keeping the order of operations while doing a sequential calculation

Tags: c++, operators

I am spending my evening doing some programming problems from Kattis. There is one part of the problem [4 thought](https://open.kattis.com/problems/4thought) that I am stuck on.

Given a number, the program is supposed to return the operations (+, -, * or /) required between 4 fours to achieve that number.

For example, the input

```
9
```

would result in the output

```
4 + 4 + 4 / 4 = 9
```

My solution (not efficient, but simple) is to evaluate all possible ways to combine the operators above and see if any of the combinations achieve the wanted result.

To do this I have written the function seen below. It takes in an array of chars which are the operators to be evaluated (`uo[3]`, could look like `{+, /, *}`), and the wanted result as an integer (`expRes`).

```
bool check(char uo[3], int expRes) {
    int res = 4;
    for(int oPos = 2; oPos >= 0; oPos--) {
        switch (uo[oPos]) {
            case '+' : res += 4; break;
            case '-' : res -= 4; break;
            case '*' : res *= 4; break;
            case '/' : res /= 4; break;
        }
    }
    return res == expRes;    
}
```

I realized that this "sequential" approach comes with a problem: it doesn't follow the order of operations. If I was to call the function with
`uo = {+, -, /}`
and
`expRes = 7` it would return false since 4 + 4 = 8, 8 - 4 = 4, 4 / 4 = 1.
The real answer is obviously true, since 4 + 4 - 4 / 4 = 7.

Can any of you think of a way to rewrite the function so that the evaluation follows the order of operations?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Its an easy problem if you look at it.

You are restricted with four 4's and three operators in between, that is you already know your search space. So one solution is to generate the complete search space which is O(n^3) = 4^3 = 64 total equations, where n is the number of operators. Keep the answer to these solutions as a `<key, value>` pair so that look up to the input of test case is O(1).

Step wise you'd do.

1. Generate Complete Sequence and store them as key, value pairs
2. Take Input from test cases
3. Check if key exists, if yes print the sequence, else print that the sequence doesn't exist
4. Solution would take 64*1000 operations, which can easily be computed with in a second and would avoid Time Limit Exceeded Error that usually these competitions have

in Code form (most of it is incomplete):

```
// C++ Syntax
map<int, string> mp;

void generateAll() {
    // generate all equations
}

void main () {
    generateAll();

    int n, t; scanf("%d", &t);
    while (t--) {
        scanf("%d", &n);

        if ( mp.find(n) != mp.end() ) 
            // equation exists to the input
        else
            // equation doesn't exist for the input
    }
}
```